# Outlook MacOS, block sending invites by subject or user

Tags: macos, email, microsoft-outlook, calendar

Some people are sending me invites with a specific topics and though I've blocked the senders, the events they send are still appearing in my calendar. Rules for automatically marking an email for deleting are not working for calendar, as though the emails deleted and/or marked as junk that does not help with meeting still appearing in the calendar.

Is it possible to completely block spam invitations with some specific words in the subject or at least from specific users? Unfortunately, googling didn't give me the answer.

Here is my Outlook version.

[image: Here is my Outlook version.]

Update:
Sorry if I wan't clear enough. All I want is to prevent unwanted invitations/events appearing in my calendar. I tried using options "Block sender" in the message, "Mark as Junk" and automatically deleting those messages or marking them as junk by using specific rules, however that didn't work. Though the messages are in junk/deleted folders, the invitations are still appearing in the calendar.

I've also tried searching for ways to categorise those meetings automatically and then filter them out in the calendar (that would also be acceptable for me), but it seems like this functionality was removed from Outlook on Mac.

Comment: You do understand, that once you have received an email, all you can do is configure a rule to handle it.  If you want to block a sender, that requires the IT Administrator, to block it at the server level.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, probably I wan't clear enough. All I want is to prevent unwanted invitations to appear in my calendar. I tried to use options "Block sender" in the message, "Mark as Junk" and automatically deleting those messages by using specific rules, however that didn't work.

Comment: I have done the same test in my Outlook for Mac, but get the same results as yours. I'm afraid that you need to delete the calendar events manually.